# Keras - How to construct a shared Embedding() Layer for each Input-Neuron

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I want to create a deep neural network in keras, where each element of the input layer is "encoded" using the same, shared Embedding()-layer, before it is fed into the deeper layers.

Each input would be a number that defines the type of an object, and the network should learn an embedding that encapsulates some internal representation of "what this object is".

So, if the input layer has X dimensions, and the embedding has Y dimensions, the first hidden layer should consist of X*Y neurons (each input neuron embedded).

[Here is a little image that should show the network architecture that I would like to create, where each input-element is encoded using a 3D-Embedding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quise.png)

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to keep your hidden representation in form of multiple outputs or do you want them to create a single feature vector?

Comment: It should be multiple distinct outputs in the first hidden layer, one for each input. Please have a look at my second comment below Nassim Ben's answer. Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding

first_input = Input(shape = (your_shape_tuple) )
second_input = Input(shape = (your_shape_tuple) )
...

embedding_layer = Embedding(embedding_size)

first_input_encoded = embedding_layer(first_input)
second_input_encoded = embedding_layer(second_input)
...

Rest of the model....
```

The emnedding_layer will have shared weights. You can do this in form of lists of layers if you have a lot of inputs.

If what you want is transforming a tensor of inputs, the way to do it is :

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding

# If your inputs are all fed in one numpy array :
input_layer = Input(shape = (num_input_indices,) )

# the output of this layer will be a 2D tensor of shape (num_input_indices, embedding_size)
embedded_input = Embedding(embedding_size)(input_layer)
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much. Can't test it right now, have some hardware problems :\

The first looks like what I want. Tough, can I still feed it a tensor of inputs that way? So that Keras treats the Input as one layer (= I feed 1 Vector), and not as a dozend individual inputs.

The second, is it correct that it would embedd the WHOLE tensor as "one object", or does it embedd every element of the input vector on its own and individually?

Comment: Describe in more details a usecase of what you want. Write an example with the inputs you want to feed, their shape, and also what output (and its shape) do you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I want to implement a simple reinforcement learning algorithm.

But instead of letting a CNN do the feature-extraction//object-detection, I want to tell the algorithm what object is visible on what position in the screen.

So, like this http://imgur.com/a/ouidO (excuse the Paint skills).

But I would like to train an internal representation - or embedding - that captures as "what each object.. is". 

So, the network should learn a shared, internal representation of these object-IDs

Comment: Then your input is a tensor of shape (batch_size, num_of_cell_in_grid). And you can use the second solution I wrote up there, you will get a tensor of shape (batch_size, num_of_cells_in_grid, embedding_size) as an output. Every cell of your grid will have a vector associated to it which will represent the index of object that is inside. Is it clear ?

Comment: Yes it is, seems I had a misunderstanding of how the Embedding() Layer is designed. Thank you very much for your kind help!:)